# Restrict access to the site for specific role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have 3 roles: `Registered Users, Approved Users, and Admins.`
Access to the site is only available to `Approved users` and `Admins.`

To restrict anonymous access I've added a filter in `FilterConfig` as follows:

```
filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

Now, for registered users I want them to redirect to a landing page saying:

> Please contact one of the administrators to approve you.

I'm not really sure what's the correct way to do that.
I can setup authorize attribute on each of the controllers, but I'm not sure if that's a good way.
Also, I'm not sure where I should specify default redirect action based on the role.
I know that I can specify default redirect action in `RouteConfig.cs` but not sure where to specify a role.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you want. Do you want to allow access to page to authenticated users but redirect other to login? Do you want to give access to a page to authorized users but not to authenticated users who lack proper role?

Comment: @DaveA, if user is anonymous show only login, if user is registered show landing page, for all other roles show full website

Comment: Ok, I half understand. If user is authenticated allow access, otherwise redirect to login. But the rest, is a little confusing. Other roles? Other than what?

Comment: @DaveA, sorry for being unclear. What I want to do is: if a user registers on a website, I want them first to be approved by admins before they can use the site. Admins can set appropriate ApprovedRole for any of the registered users. Do this make sense?

Comment: More clear. explain the workflow. I'm a new user who registered. What happens from there. Am I redirected to an information page until I have the proper Role?

Comment: see my answer. is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StanK is right that having `[Authorize]` attribute will redirect all users who are not logged-in to the login page. That's half of your dillema.

From there you need to alter your `logon` method to check if a newly logged-in user has the right role (e.g. `ConfirmedUser`). This is tricky because `User.IsInRole("ConfirmedUser")` will always be false in your `logon` method. This is because the `User` object is populated by the http object, which will not be re-populated until the next re-cycle. Luckily, you can use the `Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, "ConfirmedUser")` to check if the user has the right role.

So, within your logon method, after authenticating user, log the user out and re-direct them to an `[AllowAnonymous]` method which informs them that they are not yet confirmed.

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, "ConfirmedUser")
{
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                return RedirectToAction("WarningMsg", "Home");

}
```

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to try this out, but it works great. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Funny enough, looking over my code I made a mistake. The if statement should check the user did NOT have the role -- (!Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, "ConfirmedUser")). But I guess you came to the right conclusion on your own :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `[Authorize]` attributes for this.

Restricted pages will have their controller or action decorated with `[Authorize(Roles="Approved User,Admin")]`, the 'landing page' for registered users would be `[Authorize(Roles="Registered User,Approved User,Admin")]` and the Logon action would have `[AllowAnonymous]`.

If the user is not authorised, they would be re-directed to `Account/Login`.  You would need to build some logic in this action that redirects "Registered Users" who are already logged in to your landing page.  Others should just see the standard login page.

**EDIT**

The logic to redirect "Registered Users" from the login page to the landing page would look something like this

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Roles.IsUserInRole("Registered User"))
        return RedirectToAction("LandingPage");

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: **You would need to build some logic in this action that redirects "Registered Users" who are already logged in to your landing page.** I think that IS the part the OP is struggling with.